# why in array undefined?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

mycode

> https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-thompson-w7v9c2?file=/index.tsx

```
<Formik
        initialValues={initialValues}
        onSubmit={async (values) => {
          await new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, 500));
          // alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
          values.product.map((item, i: number) => {
            let qty: number[] = [];
            console.log(i + "-------qty------");
            console.log(item.qty);
            console.log(i + "-------price------");
            console.log(item.price);

            if (item.qty! && item.price!) {
              qty[i] = item.qty * item.price;

              console.log(qty);
            }
              const result = qty.reduce((sum, number) => {
                return sum + number;
              }, 0);
              setSum(result)
            console.log("-------result------");
            console.log(result);

            console.log("-------Sum------");
            console.log(sum);
            console.log("-------langth------");
            console.log(i);
          });
        }}
      >
```

I added the price and qty to the contiguous array.
and i need `price + qty` combined but **result**
array `[ undefined, 30]` or `[undefined,undefined ,40]`
When I add data to an array i want to record in `const [sum, setSum] = useState(0)`

Comment: use this check before map ```{array && array.map (ele => <>{ele} </>)```

Comment: using && operators helps with the case, but if its falsy,  it returns 0, which is ugly for the  UI, instead, use ? like this - {array ? array.map (ele => <>{ele} </> : "this is better")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting `sum` for each product, at every iteration. You may want to do some reading: [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```
<Formik
        initialValues={initialValues}
        onSubmit={async (values) => {
          await new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, 500));
          // alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
          const result = values.product.reduce((sum, p) => {
                return sum + p.qty * p.price;
              }, 0);
          setSum(result)
          
            console.log(result);

          });
        }}
      >
```

Answer (score 1):

your if condition is wrong. replace this

```
        if (item.qty! && item.price!) {
```

with this

```
        if (!item.qty && !item.price) {
```